Work publishable at conference
In the course of writing my master's thesis, I developed a new algorithm that outperforms several state-of-the-art algorithms. However, I have encountered a study that uses a similar idea but implements it in a more complex manner, which also presents several disadvantages. Given this context, I am trying to determine if my approach is sufficiently novel?
How would determine this?

Have you asked your advisor? This is what they are for.

Yes I will do that, but from what you reading, what is your opinion?

It all depends on details that we don't know, in particular, how similar exactly is the "similar idea", how severe are the disadvantages, at what level will you try to publish it, and how convincing is your "outperforming" case - it can be surprisingly easy for a method developer to make their method look better than some competitors, and sometimes when others try the new method out, these results do not replicate. (And I'm not talking about cheating here - rather you know how to use your own method in the best way, but maybe not the competitors.)

This is not a place to ask for opinions.

@ChristianHennig: Thank you for your answer. Simply speaking, I want to achieve a related goal, but can achieve that in a much simpler fashion. The disadvantages are severe in that sense, that extra steps have to be done, which might not be practical, to make their approach work. The problem is, I found the approach after I developed mine, but this hard to prove.

If your new algorithm has all the advantages you claim, it should be publishable. Just cite the other work and say what the advantages of your work are. Obviously nobody here can ultimately assess the quality, importance and novelty of what you have, so other than asking your supervisor the only thing you can do is submit it and see what the reviewers say.

At least it should be enough for a master thesis. Thank you.
